# Regex for UK registration number

Tags: regex

I've been playing with creating a regular expression for UK registration numbers but have hit a wall when it comes to restricting overall length of the string in question. I currently have the following:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]?){1,3}(\d){1,3}([a-zA-Z]?){1,3})
```

This allows for an optional string (lower or upper case) of between 1 and 3 characters, followed by a mandatory numeric of between 1 and 3 characters and finally, a mandatory string (lower or upper case) of between 1 and 3 characters.

This works fine but I then want to apply a max length of 7 characters to the entire string but this is where I'm failing. I tried adding a 1,7 restriction to the end of the regex but the three 1,3 checks are superseding it and therefore allowing a max length of 9 characters.

Examples of registration numbers that need to pass are as follows:

- A1
- AAA111
- AA11AAA
- A1AAA
- A11AAA
- A111AAA

In the examples above, the A's represents any letter, upper or lower case and the 1's represent any number. The max length is the only restriction that appears not to be working. I disable the entry of a space so they can be assumed as never present in the string.

Comment: You do realise that your spec for UK registration numbers is not correct ? It doesn't work for vehicles prior to 1963, for example, or military vehicles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom,_Crown_dependencies_and_overseas_territories

Comment: Depending on your actual use case, you may want to exclude ones that match the patterns but aren't actually valid plates still - ones that have been scrapped etc - if the business case is there and you're able, perhaps you should do realtime lookups to a service providing such information?

Comment: Not too fussed about pre-1963 or military vehicles for my purpose. As for the use of a service, that occurs after the client-side regex validation already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what lengths you are after, I'd recommend you use the `.length` property which some languages expose for string length. If this is not an option, you could try using something like so: `^(?=.{1,7})(([a-zA-Z]?){1,3}(\d){1,3}([a-zA-Z]?){1,3})$`, example [here](https://regex101.com/r/hP9nL6/1).